# calculate the value of P is the points A(6;5), B(3;2) and C (2p;p+4) are co-linnear

Tags: analytic-geometry, graphing-functions

Also honestly have no clue whatsoever. I have tried jotting down a graph and just finding the differences between A and B and minusing them from B to create C. I know this is completely wrong! Please help :)

Comment: Hint: if they are collinear, then $AB$ has the same slope as $BC$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that all of the points lie on the same line; call it $L$. We can use the first two points to find the slope of $L$, which we call $m$.

$$
m=\frac{2-5}{3-6}=\frac{-3}{-3}=1.
$$

Now, we can write out an equation for $L$: $y=mx+b=x+b$ To find $b$, we plug in the point $A$: $5=6+b\implies b=-1$. Thus, the equation for $L$ is $y=x-1$. Now, we plug the point $C$ into this and solve for $p$:

$$
p+4=2p-1\implies p=5.
$$